# Эффект позиционирования связанный с прокруткой - предупреждение при прокрутке в Firefox

Tags: firefox, прокрутка

В проекте используются собственные реализации прокрутки и эффекты, связанные с прокруткой. Буквально сегодня появилось предупреждение в Firefox при прокрутке страницы, текст следующий:

> Похоже, что этот сайт использует эффект позиционирования связанный с прокруткой. Это может не очень хорошо работать с асинхронным панорамированием; см. https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects чтобы получить более подробную информацию и присоединиться к обсуждению связанных с этим инструментов и возможностей!

Почитал информацию по ссылке, там описание так называемой "асинхронной прокрутки", "липкого позиционирования" и пр., но так и не понял, с чем может быть связана проблема и что такое "асинхронное панорамирование".

Comment: Асинхронное программирование - это когда процедуры в общей массе не последовательно выполняются - а по событию/таймеру/таймеру из события/... . Если фаерфокс предупреждает - значит лучше действительно подумать насчёт этих эффектов.

Comment: @Гончаров Александр, спасибо, я понимаю, что такое "асинхронное программирование", я не понимаю, что такое "асинхронное панорамирование" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По всей видимости, всё довольно просто: предполагаю, что Firefox "парсит" подгруженный на страницу js-код и, если находит свойства позиционирования внутри функции onscroll или - при использовании jQuery - внутри метода .scroll(), то выдаёт подобное предупреждение. Следующие примеры кода в Firefox-е (проверялось в версии 47.0.1) вызовут предупреждение:

```
<style>
.wrapper {
    margin: 0;
}
.scrolled_block {
    position: absolute;
    height: 400%;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="wrapper"> 
    <div class="scrolled_block"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Romanzhivo/mbmwdo2t/

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('scrolled_block')[0].style.top = 20 + 'px'
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Romanzhivo/mbmwdo2t/2

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.scrolled_block').css({
        'top': '10px',
        'left': '10px'
    }) 
});
```